# Calculate $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n}{n!} \int_0^\infty x^{s + n - 2} dx$

Tags: riemann-zeta

By Taylor expanding

$$\frac{x}{e^{x}-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n}{n!}x^n$$

in the Zeta function

$$\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty x^{s-2} (\frac{x}{e^{x}-1})dx$$

we find

\begin{align}
\zeta(s) &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty x^{s-2} (\frac{x}{e^{x}-1})dx = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty x^{s-2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n}{n!}x^n dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n}{n!}  \int_0^\infty x^{s + n - 2} dx
\end{align}

what exactly do we do next to arrive [at the formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Negative_integers) for $\zeta(-n)$ and $\zeta(2n)$?

Comment: Your last integral doesn't converge, so that's not going to go anywhere.

Comment: Your expansion for $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ is only valid for $\vert x \vert < 2\pi$ ... so that could be a problem

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor expanding, for $|x| < 2 \pi$ :

$$\frac{x}{e^{x}-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n}{n!}x^n$$

in the Zeta function, for $Re(s) > 1$ :

$$\zeta(s)\Gamma(s) =  \int_0^\infty  \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x}-1}dx =  \int_0^a x^{s-2} \frac{x}{e^{x}-1}dx +  \int_a^\infty  \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x}-1}dx$$

we find whenever $0 < a < 2 \pi$ and $Re(s)> 1$, inverting $\sum$ and $\int$ by absolute/monotone/dominated convergence :

\begin{align}
\zeta(s)\Gamma(s) &=  \int_a^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x}-1}dx + \int_0^a x^{s-2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n}{n!}x^n dx \\
&= \int_a^\infty  \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x}-1}dx  + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}  \int_0^a x^{s + n - 2} dx\\
&=  \int_a^\infty  \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x}-1}dx  +  \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!} \frac{a^{s+n-1}}{s+n-1}\end{align}

note how by analytic continuation it stays valid for every $s \in \mathbb{C}$ except  at the poles,

and how it tells us the residue of $\zeta(s) \Gamma(s)$ at its poles, and hence the value of $\zeta(-k)$  for $k \in \mathbb{N}$